# Facebook Connect - localization

Tags: iphone, facebook

I am working on an iPhone app that use Facebook Connect. Its working fine but I need to localize the Facebook connect dialog into French. Is this possible ? Please give your thoughts and if possible I like to know the way it can be done.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd recommend you use the new facebook-ios-sdk instead of the old Facebook Connect. Then, the dialog is a webview so you can't (and don't need to) localize its content, Facebook already does that for you ;-) At least I can confirm that with facebook-ios-sdk, tried English, German and Japanese.

Comment: Thanks DarkDust for your answer. Actually When one of my friends ask this question I told him to change the language settings to French and try but he didn't replay me with the result. So I thought its now working. But when I try after your answer I was surprised. Once again Thanks.